# If $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$, then where does $|h|$ spring from?

Tags: real-analysis

To avoid typos, please see my screen captures below, and the red underline. The question says $h \rightarrow 0$, thus why $|h|$ in the solution? Mustn't that $|h|$ be $h$?

[image]

Spivak, *Calculus* 2008 4 edn.  [His website's errata](https://mathpop.com/) lists no errata for these pages.

Comment: what if $h$ is negative?

Comment: $h\to 0$ iff $|h|\to 0.$

Comment: And that *is* the definition of $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = K$ means that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta$ so that if $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ then ..... stuff....  And so if we let $x = h$ and $a= 0$ we get $\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)$ means for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ so that $0 < |h - 0| < \delta$.  ..... Another way of putting this is $-\delta < h < \delta; h \ne 0$.  Don't forget we *can* have $h < 0$ in which case $h = -|h|$ and $-\delta < h < 0$.

Comment: @zhw.  ..... and $h \to 0$ iff $|h|\to 0$ iff $-|h| \to 0$.  (...and as we don't know if $h$ is positive or negative.....)

Comment: Note: there is a misplaced absolute value sign in the image. $|f(x) - \ell < \varepsilon|$ should read $|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Writing
$$
0 < |h| < \delta
$$
is easier than writing
$$
-\delta  < h < \delta   \text{ and } h \ne 0 .
$$

Comment: You mean $-\delta<h<\delta$, not the other way around.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Of course. Fixed it thanks. You could have.

Comment: That always feels rude to me when someone has nontrivial reputation :)

Comment: @symplectomorphic To me it feels not rude at all. We are both here to help visitors. This was an obvious typo and I'd have been delighted to  have it fixed for me. But maybe others would feel as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the definition of a limit involves the inequality $0 < |x - a| < \delta$. Substituting $a = 0$ and $x = h$ yields
$$
0 < |h| < \delta,
$$
which is the inequality that you've underlined.

Answer (score 0):

$h$ might tend to zero from either side, so the statement $$-\delta \lt h \lt \delta \iff 0\lt |h| \lt \delta$$ is required.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. It takes a while and some practice to wrap your head around this stuff. It's easy to get confused by all the different conditions and variables and what depends on what.

Suppose $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \ell$

This means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, if

$$0 < |x - a| < \delta \text{ then } |f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$$

Now, for this same $\delta$, suppose you have a number $h$ such that
$$0 < |h| < \delta$$

We can make this look like the previous condition by noting that $h = (a + h) - a$.
Therefore, for all $h$ if
$$0 < |h| < \delta$$
then
$$0 < |(a + h) - a| < \delta$$

Compare this with the initial $\delta$-requirement placed on $x$, namely $0 < |x - a| < \delta$.

The number $a+h$ satisfies the $x$ requirement from the first limit, so we have $|f(a + h) - \ell| < \varepsilon$.

Putting it all together, if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \ell$ then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $h$, if

$$0 < |h| < \delta \text { then } |f(a + h) - \ell| < \varepsilon$$

Another way of writing this is $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = \ell$. If the first limit exists, then so too does the second, and they are equal.

To complete the proof we need to begin with the second limit $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = \ell$ and use similar arguments to show how it leads to the first limit.

Suppose $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = \ell$. This tells us that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $h$, if
$$0 < |h| < \delta \text { then } |f(a + h) - \ell| < \varepsilon$$

Suppose for this same $\delta$ we have numbers $x$ such that
$$0 < |x - a| < \delta$$

Compare this with the above $\delta$-requirements for $h$. These numbers $x-a$ fulfill the $\delta$-requirements for $h$, therefore

$$|f(a + (x - a)) - \ell| < \varepsilon$$

but this is just
$$|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$$.

Putting it all together, we know that if $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = \ell$ then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, if

$$0 < |x - a| < \delta \text{ then } |f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$$

We can of course write this as $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \ell$. Again, existence of one limit guarantees existence of the other, and they are equal.